# How to use focus on a material UI Text Field using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi guys I have used material UI and react to create a form. I would like to use the focus property on a particular ref. Please find below the code for reference :-

Using createRef for initialising the reference.Following is the code for the constructor:-

```
      constructor(props) {
super(props);
    this.state = {
  gender: '',
  empType: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  officePincode: '',
  dob: '',
  mobile: '',
  monthlySalary: '',
  residentialPincode: '',
  panNumber: ''
};

this.firstNameRef = React.createRef();
this.lastNameRef = React.createRef();
this.dobRef = React.createRef();
this.emailRef = React.createRef();
this.monthlySalaryRef = React.createRef();
this.officePincodeRef = React.createRef();
this.residentialPincodeRef = React.createRef();
this.panNumberRef = React.createRef();
```

}

I am using this array in the render method:-

```
    const focusArray = [
  this.firstNameRef,
  this.lastNameRef,
  this.dobRef,
  this.emailRef,
  this.monthlySalaryRef,
  this.officePincodeRef,
  this.residentialPincodeRef,
  this.panNumberRef
];

// eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
for (let index = 0; index < focusArray.length; index++) {
  const currentRef = focusArray[index];
  if (currentRef.current) {
    if (currentRef.current.value === '') {
      currentRef.current.focus();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Please find below code for the text field:-

```
            <TextField
          id="firstName"
          name="firstName"
          ref={this.firstNameRef}
          value={firstName}
          disabled={
            firstName && disableNameField.has(params.get('utm_source'))
          }
          label="First Name"
          error={formSubmitted && !validateName(firstName)}
          onChange={this.handleChange()}
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          helperText={
            formSubmitted && !validateName(firstName)
              ? '*Please enter first name'
              : ''
          }
          className={classes.input_field}
          InputLabelProps={{
            classes: {
              root: classes.cssLabel,
              focused: classes.cssFocused
            }
          }}
          InputProps={{
            classes: {
              root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
              focused: classes.cssFocused,
              notchedOutline: firstName
                ? classes.noOutline
                : classes.notchedOutline
            }
          }}
        />
```

I am using a class based react component.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share as much of the component as relevant?

Comment: Usually with focus events, you would use a ref via `useRef` or `createRef` to access the actual (not virtual) DOM element. In this instance, you're just storing a value as a variable named ref - not the actual DOM node itself.

Comment: @Hyetigran I have shared some more code for reference.

Comment: @JoelHager I am using createRef I have updated the code for more clarity.